# Delete Phone Number validation, Error in Forms

Tags: magento-1.8, forms, form-validation, contact-form

I want to remove phone validation from this form below, it's not accepting any phone number, the file is `smiple_contact.phtml` but I am not sure what code to delete. Thanks.

http://www.b2zee.com/b2c/index.php/b2zee-tourism

Comment: Not enough characters to paste the code here, what is another method?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `validate-must-phone` class from `Contact Number` field.

For list of all available validation classes, check here : http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/

Comment: I deleted it, but when I submit the Form, an error appears.

Comment: if you don't want to validate if empty , remove `required-entry` class also

Comment: //var phoneno = /^\+[0-9]{6,20}$/;  
   
 //var phoneno =/^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[- ]?([0-9]{3})[- ]?([0-9]{5})$/;
 var phoneno =/\+(9[976]\d|8[987530]\d|6[987]\d|5[90]\d|42\d|3[875]\d|2[98654321]\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|4[987654310]|3[9643210]|2[70]|7|1)\W*\d\W*\d\W*\d\W*\d\W*\d\W*\d\W*\d\W*\d\W*(\d{1,2})$/;
 var x = document.getElementById("contact");
    var x = x.value;

  Validation.add('validate-must-phone','You failed to enter Phone no!',function(x){

        if( x.match(phoneno))  
        {

            return true;

        }else{

        return false;

Comment: I have the is also at the bottom.

Comment: Then remove this element to be validated. Try to remove `required-entry` class. Can not debug the code you posted

Comment: Still, an error appears after submitting the form, it redirects to a page that says:

Comment: There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 394795591076